# Woff fonts in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, woff

When I emebed CSS3 woff fonts:

```
@font-face{
   font-family: SomeFont;
   src: url(SomeFont.woff);
}
```

Works perfect in any browser if I use localhost or server host.

But when I create portable .html file and open it. Fonts works in any browser but not in Internet Explorer.

Why could happen this? (Outside of the fact that Internet Explore is bad)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try `src: url(SomeFont.woff) format('woff');`? Which version of IE are you testing against?

Comment: So I understand this right: when both html and woff are on your local drive, it doesn't work? (If the html is local and the woff is not, it's likely a cross-domain security issue.)